# Awk program to take file name as argument and process commands taking each line of that file

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a log file containing information of an object. I need script in AWK

My log will be like this:

```
ObjectA copy time 2ms
ObjectA ID is 23467sdfs3453AAAA
ObjectB copy time 7ms
Objectc run time 23ms
ObjectA process time 3ms
ObjectA run time 1ms
Objectc copy time 71ms
ObjectB ID is sada67AsdfsdfAA345
ObjectB process time 9ms
Objectc process time 29ms
ObjectB run time 4ms 
ObjectC ID is 534267AsdfsdfAA233

...
```

And my output should be

```
Objectname  |  Object ID          |    CopyTime |    RunTime |  ProcessTime
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ObjectA     |  23467sdfs3453AAAA   |    2ms       |    1ms      | 3ms
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ObjectB     |  sada67AsdfsdfAA345  |    7ms       |    4ms      | 9ms
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ObjectC     |  534267AsdfsdfAA233  |    71ms      |    23ms     | 29ms 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

its the complete requirement.
Kind of tabular format.

Comment: What info do you want to get for each object? Present a sample i/p and o/p

Comment: Output should be in Object A : 2+3+1 , Object B: 7+9+4 , ObjectC: 71+29+13 so that i will individual object infomation

Comment: It should be just `2+3+1` or actual summed value?

Comment: it should be 2+3+1

Comment: Can you clearify that in your question and give a proper example of the expected output?

Comment: i have a more than 1000 log files . object related information will written in those files . i need to process those files and get info of each object process timing in a separate file. object will be having different process timings.

Comment: Stop feeding us snippets of your requirements in comments and instead [edit] your question to contain all relevant information, including everything you've provided and comments AND concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `awk` script will parse the given file and store the relevant info for each object using an associative array keyed on the first column of the input.  At the end, it creates a simple table.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$2 == "copy" {
    copy_time[$1] = $NF;
}

$2 == "ID" {
    id[$1] = $NF;
}

$2 == "run" {
    run_time[$1] = $NF;
}

$2 == "process" {
    process_time[$1] = $NF;
}

END {
    fmt = "%-15s| %-20s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s\n";
    div = "------------------------------------------------------------------------------";

    printf(fmt, "Object Name", "Object ID", "Copy Time",
           "Run Time", "Process Time");
    print(div);

    for (obj in id) {
        printf(fmt, obj, id[obj], copy_time[obj],
               run_time[obj], process_time[obj]);
        print(div);
    }
}
```

Running it (with corrected capitalization of `ObjectC`):

```
$ ./script.awk data.in
Object Name    | Object ID            | Copy Time  | Run Time   | Process Time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ObjectA        | 23467sdfs3453AAAA    | 2ms        | 1ms        | 3ms
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ObjectB        | sada67AsdfsdfAA345   | 7ms        | 4ms        | 9ms
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ObjectC        | 534267AsdfsdfAA233   | 71ms       | 23ms       | 29ms
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `grep` together with `tr` as a preprocessor for the list:

```
tr ',' '\n' < objects.txt | grep -Ff- logfile
```

The `tr` command translates the objects file from a comma separated file into a file where pattern are on a separate line:

```
ObjectA
ObjectB
ObjectC
```

`grep -f-` uses this file as a list of search patterns. Note that `-` is a special value for the filename and means stdin. `-F` treats the patterns as literal strings rather than regular expressions.

Comment: Am afraid the OP needs output as `2+3+1`, i.e. values per object type :)